# Get notification when there's new update/insert in the database

Tags: jquery, django, notifications, django-signals

I have setup most of the part for an instagram like app, including the django-signals too. What I need is, whenever a user comments, or posts a new photo, I want it to notify the users without refreshing the page, like when Twitter, Stack Overflow or Facebook does when something new has been posted. How do I do it? I guess I should do this in the client side.

Comment: Those sites use websockets, and probably a river from the database.

Comment: Periodically poll with AJAX.